# Java-8 Stream, filters and map execution

Tags: java-8

I am new to java. Just found out some code which contains stream, filter, and map as well. Could you please explain how it works.

```
List<String> refs = dataDao.retrieveData(startDate, endDate);

List<String[]> csvRecords = dataDao.retrieveAllData()
        .stream()
        .filter(promo -> promoFilter(promo, startDate, endDate, refs))
        .map(this::promoSummary)
        .map(builder::toCsvRecord)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You won't probably get an answer here for that. Google is better. Take a look at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/streams.html

Answer (score 0):

You better refer to a complete lesson/tutorial, but since I just studied these concept myself I'm up to a little refresher. Don't take what I'm writing here literally: just use it to help you better understand.

A [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) is an collection that allows certain stream-operations **only once**. Think it like the stream is a blanket that gets unfold after it has been used. Streams are templates, that means you define and use streams of something. E.g: `Stream<String>`. So think the stream is a blanket rolled around... toys (I don't know, what do you roll with a blanket?).

When coding stream you abuse of [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), that means you don't store a result into a variable, but you call one of its methods on the fly. In your code the chaining happens six times!

So, let's dissect this chain:

- `dataDao.retrieveAllData()` is a proprietary method, not related to stream. I assume it returns a special object.
- `.stream()` is the first link of the chain. It returns a `Stream<XXX>`
- `.filter( )` returns the elements for the stream that passes the [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) `promo -> promoFilter(promo, startDate, endDate, refs)`. The predicate is expressed by a lambda function. But that is totally another lesson.
- `.map(F)` returns a stream that is the inputed stream modified by the function F. Again, lambda.
- `.collect` is another function that edits a stream.

Some tutorials to help with your study, in no particular order:

- [Lambda expressions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/)
- [Functional Interfaces](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-interfaces-java/)
- [Streams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams)

Hope I helped!